# How to set the datasource of RDLC to the return of a specific method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, rdlc, reportviewer, class-library

I want to set the `datasource` of my `RDLC` report to the return of a specific method .but the report wizard can't detect my methods.

[image]

The Method is in Class `Utility` in `DataLayer` namespace and my report in another class library(`FinanceReportBundle`).

**The Class is like that** :

```
namespace DataLayer
{

    public  class Utility
    {

         public static IEnumerable<object> GetAnalysisDataForConsecutiveYears(int year, int periodTypeId, int period)
        {
            ////Business
        } 
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it in the designer. You can set your data source in code easily, like this:

```
var dataSource = getmyDataSource();
var rds = new ReportDataSource("myDataSourceName", dataSource);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "path your your rdlc";
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```